# RAmazonS3 broken pipe when upload files

Tags: r, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use [RAmazonS3](http://www.omegahat.org/RAmazonS3/) to upload a local file to S3 storage, but I keep getting a broken pipe error.

```
require(RAmazonS3)
options(AmazonS3 = c('xxx' = "xxx")) #login and secret
setwd('[local directory]/reports') #set working directory to location of "polarity.png"
addFile("polarity.png", "umusergen", "destination.png",type="image/png",meta = c(foo = 123, author = "Duncan Temple Lang"))
```

> Send failure: Broken  Pipe

It works fine if I just try to upload content

`addFile(I("This is a test"), "umusergen", "destination.png",type="text",meta = c(foo = 123, author = "Duncan Temple Lang")`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

addFile() is quite simplistic and is focused on text content unless told otherwise.
Use

```
 content = readBin("polarity.png", raw(), file.info("polarity.png")[1, "size"])
```

and

```
  addFile(content, "umusergen", "destination.png", type = "image/png")
```

I'll update the addFile() function to allow one to indicate this is binary or content
or to use the (MIME) type.